# Daily API calls versus daily bandwidth usage and request time usage

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, salesforce2salesforce, visual-workflow

I am trying to find out if my organization needs additional API calls per day,

So I contacted Salesforce and my Account executive explained to me how to increase out API calls daily limit,

But he had no knowledge of our daily bandwidth usage limit or request time usage limit,

I have installed “Force.com Sites Usage Reporting” package,
And it shows me our daily bandwidth usage and request time usage limits,
So what happens when we exceed those limits?

Are these limits proportional to the daily API calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Calls aren't related to Site Usage, they refer to any call made that utilizes the API.  Typically your Site won't be using any API calls (although in theory it could) and is throttled based on bandwidth and request time usage.

Assuming you're not making any API calls in your sites (which again, would be unusual, but not unheard of) you can assume you won't need to purchase additional API calls.

Common things that do need API calls are external integrations, heroku sites, and Salesforce 2 Salesforce among others.

Comment: That's a great description, But what if I reach my daily bandwidth limit or request time usage, what happens then?

Comment: Your site gets turned off until you purchase more according the docs https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US